# How to run a local daemon with android?

Tags: monerod, compile, library, android

After some research, I found that **monerod** compiling was disabled on `get_libwallet_api`.

I enabled and everything is ok.

I tried to insert it on the apk package but inserting failed, so I compiled the apk without the Monero daemon and it works fine.

Any help on inserting **monerod** (as external binary) on an apk package?

Comment: Because you mention `get_libwallet_api` I can only presume you are trying to build the Monero GUI. Have you followed the [build instructions](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/blob/master/android/README.md)?

Comment: Yes i did everything that README says and apk is created and work! But daemon can not be inserted on apk even when i enable this line on build.sh that for some unknown reasons was disabled. cp ../$MONERO_DIR/bin/$MONEROD_EXEC $BIN_PATH

Comment: Android GUI is listed as ALPHA, but I suggest reporting on GitHub where you'll likely get help from the developers who added this Android support.